# Add Store Codes to URL

Tags: magento-2.1, base-url, store-code

In admin panel under Url options, I want to turn on Store codes on Url, since I want to visit my country-specific pages. I'm running locally (using WAMP) so my IP is 127.0.0.1:8888. I did set my host file so that magento.lan points to 127.0.0.1. Base url is set to magento.lan (but my store is still visited on magento.lan:8888).

The error I'm getting when trying to enable the store codes to url setting is:

```
Invalid domain name: The input appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list; The input does not appear to be a valid URI hostname; The input does not appear to be a valid local network name
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `web/url/use_store` in `core_config_data` table to 1 fixed the issue.